# Modelling a Bell-Shaped Growth Pattern

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

In my experiments I observed something that grows, reaches a steady-state, and then destabilizes. If the length were to be plotted as a function of time, it would look similar to a Kuznetz/Gaussian curve, only that it may not be symmetric (ie. growth > decay, or vice versa). Would anyone be aware of a function that can model both the growth and decay of such a feature?

Comment: Are you describing [something like this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a5/PDF_invGauss.svg/325px-PDF_invGauss.svg.png)?

Comment: What does it model physically? electric currrent? radiation?

Comment: @DonkeyKong Yes, very similar!

Comment: @Narasimham It models a physical filament that grows, then decays.